# Is it possible to avoid duplicate symbol when linking project

Tags: c, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I doing project which required library which I made. This library contains lot of small functions and one big, which consists of 10 files. 
Now I trying to compile my project with this lib and getting this:

```
duplicate symbol _parse_flags in:
    obj/parse_flags.o
    ./mylib/libmylib.a(parsing.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

parse_flags from mylib used only as helper function. Of course I can rename it, or put all functions except required one in same file and make them static, but maybe there another more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: `ld` does its job and wants no duplicate for a symbol linkable externally. Making `static` functions that do not need to be called outside the object is a solution (note that you don't need to move all funcs in a unique file, as the same func could be static in two files - not so clean, but these were initially defined in two files, for a reason maybe?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I should use gcc only. Also my parse_flags function is used in another file so I can't make it static. Maybe there another possibilities? Thanks.

Comment: the indications are that either there are two (or more) functions with the same name -or- there is a global variable instance.  In this scenario, it looks like there is more than one function instance named: `parse_flags()`